# Tool for tracing request in distributed architecture

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, apache-kafka

We have built a system using Kafka, Solr, Cassandra and few more distributed systems. One of the tool that we're looking to build is to trace request across these distributed systems i.e. when request was processed by Kafka, when received by solr and when response was sent back to client. Problem we're facing is, it's becoming tedious to figure where request crapped out. I want to know how other folks have solved problem like these. I know it's pretty trivial problem and can be solved in many number of ways. I just wanted to get the perspective on different solution.

Comment: You could have a request id which is uniquely generated and assigned by the client facing app and have it propagated throughout the life of the request process.

Comment: You should have a look at http://zipkin.io/

Comment: Thanks @ShivaKumarSS. I also found few other frameworks like Spring Sleuth, Dapper and HTrace.